# AngularJS style.filter doesn't apply to DOM element

Tags: angularjs

I am follow simple tutorial on Angular and Electron. The problem in my case is the angular part. I am trying to apply image filters on range input manipulation but the filters doesn't seems to apply. If I try whith another style ( let's say `imageReference.style.width = "50px"`) it works fine.
This is my controller:

```
app.controller('editCtrl', function($scope, image) {
    $scope.imagePath = image.getImagePath();
    $scope.controlsActive = false;

    let imageReference = document.getElementById('mainImage');
    let generatedStyles = "";

    $scope.effects = {
        'Brightness': {val: 100, min: 0, max: 200, delim: '%'},
        'Contrast': {val: 100, min: 0, max: 200, delim: '%'},
        'Invert': {val: 0, min: 0, max: 100, delim: '%'},
        'Hup-Rotate': {val: 100, min: 0, max: 360, delim: 'deg'},
        'Sepia': {val: 0, min: 0, max: 100, delim: '%'},
        'Grayscale': {val: 0, min: 0, max: 100, delim: '%'},
        'Saturate': {val: 100, min: 0, max: 200, delim: '%'},
        'Blur': {val: 0, min: 0, max: 5, delim: 'px'}
    }

    $scope.imageEffect = (effectName) => {
        $scope.controlsActive = true;
        $scope.activeEffect = effectName;   
    }

    $scope.setEffect = () => {
        generatedStyles = "";
        for(let i in $scope.effects){ // i = Brightness and $scope.effects[i].val
             generatedStyles += `${i}(${$scope.effects[i].val + $scope.effects[i].delim})`
        }
        imageReference.style.filter = generatedStyles;
        //Electron Tutorial 16: Crazy Images Part 7 - Adding Image Effects
    }

});
```

And my HTML :

```
<div id="imageEditor">
    <div id="preview">
        <img src="{{imagePath}}" id="mainImage">
    </div>
    <div id="imageControls" ng-show="!controlsActive">
        <div class="effectType" ng-repeat="(effect, props) in effects" ng-click="imageEffect(effect)">
            {{effect}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="liveEffects" ng-show="controlsActive">
        <div class="effect" ng-repeat="(effect, props) in effects" ng-show="effect == activeEffect">
            <div class="effectName">{{effect}}</div>
            <div class="amountDone">{{props.val + props.delim}}</div>
            <div class="range-slider">
                <input type="range" class="slider-input" min="{{props.min}}" max="{{props.max}}" ng-value="props.val" ng-model="props.val" ng-change="setEffect()">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And last, this is video that I am learning from :
[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3iRQL98sY3c)
The angular version is 1.6.9 if that matters.

Comment: Don't use DOM manipulation inside the controller. You can easly use ngStyle for your usecase.

Comment: Your advice returns `name.replace is not a function
 at cssKebabToCamel`. I created `$scope.currentEffects` in the controller and gave it the value of `generatedStyles`. Calling it like `ng-style="currentEffects"`. Is it the right way ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ng-style` you can use it as an object.

```
$scope.currentEffects = {"filter": generatedStyles}
```

The next thing is that the for loop generates a string without seperations, kinda like this:
"Brightness(100%)Contrast(100%)"

I'm not familiar with the filter propertie but i think that they need to be seperated with a whitespace.